# Find $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{2n-k}{n}(-1)^k$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

> Is there closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{2n-k}{n}(-1)^k$?

I got above expression for a counting exercise. I wonder that it might have the closed form but I am not sure yet. Can anyone have any idea? Thank you in advance !

Comment: Mathematica can't find a nice one.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A014300

Comment: Would you be fine with an expression involving the Gaussian hypergeometric function?

Comment: Hi J.M. I would be interested in any answer.

Comment: I made some manipulation that may help: $$\sum_{k=1} ^{n} \binom{2n-k}{n} (-1)^k = \sum_{k=1} ^{n} \binom{n+k-1}{n} (-1)^{n-k+1} = \sum_{j=0} ^{n-1} \binom{n+j}{n} (-1)^{n-j}$$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{2n-k}{k} = \binom{2n}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{k!(2n-k)!}{(2n)!} $$
gives:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{2n-k}{k} = (2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k \int_{0}^{1} x^{2n-k}(1-x)^k\,dx $$
hence:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{2n-k}{k} = (2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}\int_{0}^{1} x^{2n}\left(1+\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^n\,dx $$
or:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{2n-k}{k} = \color{red}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}\int_{0}^{1} x^n(2x-1)^n\,dx}. $$

The RHS is a hypergeometric function, with a nice integral representation.

Comment: +1. It seems there is no way to avoid the *hyper$\ldots$*

Comment: @FelixMarin: it looks to me, too. But the last integral is easy to estimate by breaking the integration range into $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\cup\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right)$, so it is not difficult to exhibit tight asymptotics.